# Probability of getting a white ball.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have the following tasks:

I have two boxes:

Box 1: **4 white balls and 3 black balls**

Box 2: **2 white balls and 1 black ball.**

**Two random balls** are picked from **box 1 and transferred to box 2.**
Then **two random balls** are picked from **box 2 and transferred to box 1**.

Then we pick a random ball from box 2. What is the probability the ball to be white?

So my aproach was to calculate all possible cases.

Case 1: Two white balls are transferred (box 1->box2) then two white balls are transfered(box2->box1). Now what is the probability of picking a white ball.

Case 2: ...

and so on. And then sum the cases.
The problem is that this is not an easy tasks. There are 9 cases and the calculations are heavy.

Is there an easier way for solving this problem? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I think this response should be in the comments rather than as an answer, but I don't have enough reputation, so... yeah.

The second step (i.e. 2 balls transferred from Box 2 to Box 1) doesn't actually affect the probability.

Think about the case where you have 5 balls, say 3 are white and 2 are black, and you first remove 2 balls randomly then pick one ball out of the remaining 3. You can do some math on it, but what is really happening is just you picking one ball out of the 5 possible balls from the bag. 4 balls are left unpicked anyway, no matter how many balls you first remove.

After disregarding the second transfer, you can split the 3 cases of the first transfer (2W, 1W1B, 2B) and add up the probabilities to get the final answer.